# How to display not duplicate value in 2 combobox django form

Tags: python, django

I have 2 combobox in django form and both of them display same resource from db. Example: I have a table Country in db include value: 'USA', 'Japan', 'England'. Now I have 2 combobox get data from table Country to display value, If in combobox1(from_country) I choose 'USA' then combobox2(to_country) just played 'Japan' and 'England' not display 'USA' again. How can I do that? This is my forms.py file

```
class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
def label_from_instance(self, obj):
    return obj.name

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
from_country = MyModelChoiceField(queryset=None, empty_label='---Select---',
                                   widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                                   error_messages={'required': 'This field is required.'})
to_country = MyModelChoiceField(queryset=None, empty_label='---Select---',
                                 widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                                 error_messages={'required': 'This field is required.'})
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ExchangeRateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['from_country'].queryset = Country.objects.filter(is_hidden=0)
    self.fields['to_country'].queryset = Country.objects.filter(is_hidden=0)
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use javascript for this purpose.

Comment: This is too broad for me to answer here.

Comment: everyone Please help me